# Android-AnimatorSet Listener does not work

Tags: android, events, animation, set, listener

im trying to set an animator listener so in the end the objectanimators something happens ! Here is my code so far :

```
 as=new AnimatorSet();
        as.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                om.Initialize();
                System.out.println("GotIn");
                DataBase.eaten=false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

        float distance=CalcDistance();
        float angle=CalcAngle();
        tongue.setPivotX(2);
        tongue.setPivotY(0);
        rotate_tongue=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tongue, "rotation",0,90+angle);
        rotate_tongue.setDuration(0);
        rotate_tongue.start();
        tongue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        scale_tongue=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tongue,"scaleY",1.0f,1.0f*(distance/4));
        scale_tongue.setDuration(500);
        shrink_tongue=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tongue,"scaleY",1.0f*(distance/4),1.0f);
        shrink_tongue.setDuration(400);


        as.play(rotate_tongue).with(scale_tongue).before(shrink_tongue);
        as.start();
```

the problem is that the Listener doesnt actually work as nothing happens when the animatorsetend ! How to fix this ? thank you !

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

try this, if you still haven't figured it out in 3 years :)

```
    as.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            // your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's a neat solution. and makes the code shorter. I had a similar issue to OP, only the `onAnimationRepeat()` was never called. It wasn't called with this either, while setting it an the individual animation worked, both ways. Would be interesting to know why...